# Calling A JFrame method from Another JFrame

Tags: java, swing, methods, jframe, multiple-instances

I'm looking to find a solution too my issue. Currently I have 2 `JFrames` and 1 utilities class in my netbeans project. I'm no expert on java so please bear with me. I've tried looking through the java docs and on this site but cannot seem to find a solution to my problem.

Here is the scenario:

My launcher class launches the `JFrame` called **MainForm.java** the form then initializes components onto the screen. On this form I have a button that launches a new form called **ConfigEditor.java**. This form is used to edit a config file. I have a **Save** button on this form, and what I basically want to do is once I click save get the **MainForm.java** to call a method to fill in the right components with the new values.

Heres an example, heres some of the code from my Save button on the **ConfigEditor.java**:

```
if(reply == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
        try {
            Utilities.writeConfigFileBasic(ExecutionLists.getText(),DefaultResultsFile.getText(), 
                    DefaultTestDir.getText(), Environments.getText(), ResultsViewerFile.getText());
            ConfigTextArea.append(Utilities.readConfigFile());
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Saved");
```

Now just after the last line I want to call somthing like `MainForm.initMyComponents()`; as this method exists in the `MainForm` `JFrame` but it wont let me call this. The purpose of that method is to populate some of the fields with data extracted from a config file.
I'm sorry if I haven't explained it very well, I'm fairly new to Java if you need any clarification please let me know and I'll do my best to clarify it.

Comment: use CardLayout instead of multiple instances, this could be road to hell for newbee

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Comment: In my opinion its all subjective. I believe for my application using 2 frames is more preferable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you simply pass a reference of MainForm to ConfigEditor when it is constructed? For instance:

```
... //Code fired by clicking the button you mentioned which is in class MainFrame
ConfigEditor configEditor = new ConfigEditor(this); //This would be a reference to your MainFrame
```

With this reference you can then call your desired method in the MainFrame class.

Comment: I'll give that a shot as soon as I get home. Im not sure how that works though? Would that go into the MainForm code?

Comment: That is correct. Your constructor for 'ConfigEditor' would then look something like this: 'ConfigEditor(MainFrame mainFrame)'  You can then call 'mainFrame.initMyComponents()'

Comment: Fantastic Michael thanks very much for your suggestion you're helping me understand it a bit more now. Sorry I cant upvote your answer I dont have enough rep.

Comment: No problem. This is what stackoverflow is all about! Good luck.